# Powershell/Batch Script to find number of file types in specified folders

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a script to count how many XML files are in certain directories.

In the main directory there are multiple folders which contain XML files and i need to find out how many of these folder contain more than one XML file.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Yes, this can be done. If you are more specific in your question, you may receive more specific answers... Anyway, as a starting point, take a look at the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), [redirection/pipes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and its `/C` option...

Comment: you can search for the files recursively or jist on level one.Which one you need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done by using `Get-ChildItem` with `-Filter`.
Force the result to an array and get the `count` field from the array. For example.

```
@(Get-ChildItem -Path "folder1","folder2" -Filter "*.xml").count
```

Note that `@()` forces the result of `Get-ChildItem` to an array.

If you need to also search subfolders, use `-Recurse` with `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 0):

The following may give you the 'number of first level directories' within `C:\MainDirectory` which contain more than `1` `XML` file.

```ps1
$(GCI 'C:\MainDirectory'|?{$_.PSIsContainer -And @(GCI $_.Fullname -Fi *.xml|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -Gt 1}).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

"good old" batch command to do this is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set thePath=<YOUR_PATH>

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%a IN (`DIR /AD /B /S "!thePath!"`) DO (

    FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%g IN (`dir /S /B "%%a\*.xml" ^| FIND /I /C ".xml"`) DO (
    SET /A numXml=%%g

    IF /I !numXml! GEQ 2 (
     ECHO "%%a" contains more than 1 xml file>>output.txt
    )
    )
)
```

It works all the ways through the subfolders, even if are nested n times..
It'll find out everyone that contains more than a single xml.

:-)